# Alternatives for red/green in diff output

Tags: colors, diff

I once read an article arguing that red and green are bad choices for diff, because

- some people have red-green color blindness
- red implies "bad" and green implies "good", but deleted code is often not bad and new code is also not always good.

However, I cannot remember where I found that article and which alternative colors were suggested.

What would be sensible alternative colors for red/green?

Comment: Great question for https://ux.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Umm...Blue for "good" and black for "bad"

Comment: Roy, can I move the question or should I just create a duplicate on ux.stackexchange.com?

Comment: For the record: A duplicate of this question was posted on UX and got some good answers: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/110634/alternatives-for-red-green-in-diff-output

Answer (score 1):

Since the red/green colors in diff output represent two extremes on the same axis (added code, deleted code), what you are looking for is a *diverging colorblind-safe color palette*. There are many resources available online, but ColorBrewer <sup>[1](https://colorbrewer2.org)</sup> is a popular one. After selecting for colorblind safe, here are some of the palettes ColorBrewer produced:

[image: diverging colorblind-safe color palettes]

And here is what options I selected to produce those palettes:

[image: ColorBrewer colorblind safe]

If you're interested in learning more about this kind of stuff, I'd recommend looking up different data visualization techniques.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's still here - I'd go with blue and red. Blue is more neutral, and red at least has a connotation of "deleted".